# How to bind this in function?

Tags: angular

I have this function but when i put this line on start:
      `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` it works, but its not working when i put it in where is right now in my code bellow. Any suggestion?

```
 submitLogin(values){

      // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
         let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
         loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
         loginOperation.subscribe(
            function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
            function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
            function(){
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
               console.log("the subscription is completed");


             }
        );

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use current because `this` is not recognised in javascript.

```
submitLogin(values){
    var current = this;
    Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
    let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
    loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
    loginOperation.subscribe(
    function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
    function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
    function(){ current.router.navigate(['/home']);
                console.log("the subscription is completed"); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ES6 syntax to ignore this or store the instance of `this` into a variable

```
submitLogin(values){
 var vm = this;
      // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
         let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
         loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
         loginOperation.subscribe(
            function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
            function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
            function(){
              vm.router.navigate(['/home']);
               console.log("the subscription is completed");
             }
        );

   }
```

or you can do this with ES6

```
submitLogin(values){
      // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
         let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
         loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
         loginOperation.subscribe(
           (response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
           (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
           () => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
               console.log("the subscription is completed");
             }
        );

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using angular 2 use `ARROW FUNCTIONS () => {}`

```
loginOperation.subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log("Success Response" + response)
  }, (error: any) => {
          console.log("Error happened" + error)
  }, () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          console.log("the subscription is completed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the function keyword in your subscribe handlers causes a new JavaScript scope to be created. What this means in practical terms is that within those handlers, the this keyword points to something else, not your class.

The two ways around it are to either capture a reference to your component outside your subscribe handlers and use that reference when you need to access members of your component or to bypass the problem altogether by using es2015 style arrow function declarations which do not introduce a new scope and hence don't affect the value of the this keyword

Method 1:

```
onLogin() {
  let component = this;
   ...
  loginOperation.subscribe(
        function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
        function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
        function(){
          component.router.navigate(['/home']);
           console.log("the subscription is completed");


         }
    );


}
```

Method 2 (preferable):

```
onLogin() {
     let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
     loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
     loginOperation.subscribe(
        (response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
        (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
        () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
           console.log("the subscription is completed");

         }
    );
```